# How to check eloquent relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

So i need to check for existing relationship inside the User model, and make if statement to give route access to user who has Company relationship.

User.php

```
public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'user_id');
}
```

Company.php

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User') ;
}
```

ListingController.php

```
public function create(User $user){
    if(count($user->company) > 0){
    return view('listings.create');
    } else{
    return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Navigation view

```
@inject('user', 'App\User')
    @if(count($user->company) > 0)
      <li><a href="{{route('listings.create', [$area])}}">Add Listing</a></li>
    @endif
```

Listing routes inside web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/listing', 'namespace' => 'Listing'], function (){
//        Route::get('/me', 'ListingController@userListingsView')->name('listings.index');
        Route::get('/favourites', 'ListingFavoriteController@index')->name('listings.favourites.index');
        Route::post('/{listing}/favourites', 'ListingFavoriteController@store')->name('listings.favourites.store');
        Route::delete('/{listing}/favourites', 'ListingFavoriteController@destroy')->name('listings.favourites.destroy');
        Route::post('{listing}/contact', 'ListingContactController@store')->name('listings.contact.store');

        Route::get('{listing}/share', 'ListingShareController@index')->name('listings.share.index');
        Route::post('{listing}/share', 'ListingShareController@store')->name('listings.share.store');

        Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function (){
            Route::get('/create', 'ListingController@create')->name('listings.create');
            Route::post('/', 'ListingController@store')->name('listings.store');
            Route::get('{listing}/edit', 'ListingController@edit')->name('listings.edit');
            Route::patch('{listing}', 'ListingController@update')->name('listings.update');
        });

    });
```

URL :: project.dev/{area}/listing/create

Now i'm not sure if my company relationship between user is correct and when i login with user that has company relationship it still redirect me back instead of going to create listing route.

Comment: In Navigation view, what exactly is $area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the solutions that way. My friend helped me out, so big thanks to him. Anyway here's the solutions.

Inside my navigation.blade.php, i made this if condition to find user with company relationship.

```
                   @if(count(\App\User::where(['id' => Auth::user()->id])->with('company')->first()->company) > 0 )
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{route('listings.create', [$area])}}">Lisa kuulutus</a>
                        </li>
                    @endif
```

And found that inside Company.php model relationship was belongsTo instead of hasMany.

`public function user() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

try empty function instead of count

```
public function create(User $user) {
    if (!empty($user->company)) {
        return view('listings.create');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

update Routes (create line) to

```
Route::get('{user}/create', 'ListingController@create')->name('listings.create');
```

then in your URL add user id

```
URL :: project.dev/{area}/listing/{user}/create
```

Navigation view

```
@inject('user', 'App\User')
    @if(count($user->company) > 0)
      <li><a href="{{route('listings.create', [$area, $user->id])}}">Add Listing</a></li>
    @endif
```

Comment: hmm..still redirects back, even with account with company relationship.

Comment: make sure the user object coming with data not null also check your routes by this command   php artisan route:list

Comment: you may need this php artisan route:cache

Comment: I did route:list & route:cache, everything seemed okay, but still doesn't work. But now i made dd() instead of redirecting back and got this.   #relations: array:1 [▼
    "company" => null
  ]

Comment: try to print $user obj before if statment

Comment: could you upload your routes code of create function and url

Comment: Updated the question with routes and url, and tried to print $user; comes up with empty array. :/

Comment: ahh I think I got the problem you must add user pram here Route::get('{user}/create', 'ListingController@create')->name('listings.create'); and then add it in url  look at updated answer

Comment: Okay i updated everything. Now when i go to project.dev/{area}/listing/{user}/create, i'm getting this instance error. `FatalThrowableError in ListingController.php line 30:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Listing\ListingController::create() must be an instance of App\User, string given` in line 30 `public function create(User $user){}` starts

Comment: Added $user->id, still getting the same error and when using navbar button, then i' getting this url http://project.dev/{area}/listing//create

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144133/discussion-between-mohammed-zaki-and-vaporfibe).

Answer (score 0):

Ok why don't you try this:

In Navigation view:

```
@inject('user', 'App\User')
    @if(count($user->company) > 0)
      <li><a href="{{route('listings.create', ['id' => $user->id])}}">Add Listing</a></li>
    @endif
```

And in your web.php:

```
Route::get('/create/{id}', 'ListingController@create')->name('listings.create');
```

And in your ListingController:

```
public function create($id){

    $user = User::find($id);

    if(count($user->company) > 0){
    return view('listings.create');
    } else{
    return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```